# How to export csv file from json array using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, export-to-csv

How to export json array to csv file in node js ? Below is format of json data which need to convert to csv file. Please advise.

I want to display only three column of values from json data. Column A : total number of response , Column B : Name , Column C : field1

Here is my code :

```
var json2csv = require('json2csv');
var fields = ['total', 'results.name.val'];
var csv = json2csv({ data: data, fields: fields });

fs.writeFile('file.csv', csv, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('file saved');
});
```

Using this code i got total but name column coming as empty.
Columns name are:
**total , name , field1**

```
{"total":1996,
    "results":
            [
                {
                    "name":
                    {
                        "val":"test value1",
                        "id":"0271b276",
                        "type":"String",
                    },
                    "comments":[],
                    "attributes":
                            [
                                {

                                    **"val":"test value2 ",
                                    "type":"field1",**

                                },
                                {

                                    "val":"test description",
                                    "type":"field2",

                                },
                                {

                                    "val":"test123",
                                    "type":"field3",

                                }
                            ],
                    "type":
                            {
                                    "val":"Business1",
                                    "type":"string",

                            },
                    "context":
                                {
                                    "val":"contecxt1",
                                    "type":"string",

                                },
                    "status":"Accepted",
                    "parents":[]
}]}
```

Comment: There are a lot of ways this could be done. Have you tried anything so far? I doubt you'll get anyone to write an entire tool for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
results[0].name.val
results[1].name.val
results[2].name.val
```

You need to do the rest [here is some further hint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv)